# How to store multiple values in one field of a MySQL table column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to create table `stops` for all stops with these columns `id, name,route, lat, long, arrivaltime` but I dont know how can I manage it to get the route column in the stops table? since the one route has many numbers?

```
{
   "id": 1
   "stops_name": "Amersham ",
   "route": "8,4,7,34,45,8017, 57, 20,......... 30 entries"
   "arrival_time": {
                    "mon-fri": [ "05:38", "06:07","06:37",.....50 entries],
                    "sat": ["05:34","06:01","06:31",...........50 entries],
                    "son": ["06:02","06:34","07:04",...........50 entries]
                   },
    "stops_lat": 83.837994,
    "stops_long": 18.700423
 }



stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops"
        + "(stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
        + " name varchar(30) NOT NULL, "
        + " route INT(11) NOT NULL, "
        + " lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, "
        + " longi double(10,6)NOT NULL) " );

stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
        +  " weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
        + "arrivaltime time NOT NULL,"
        + " stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id) )" );
```

Comment: I'm a SQL neophyte, so that's why I'm commenting and not answering, but an SQL column cannot contain an array or  a list. My thinking is that you would want to create another table, one that uses stops and route as foreign key and that holds a single route entry, and then link tables.

Comment: [for example and a possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way. Represent this:

```
"route": "8,4,7,34,45,8017, 57, 20,......... 30 entries"
```

Like this:

```
"route": { "8"
         , "4"
         , "7"
         , "34"
         , "45"
         , ...
         }
```

Consider representing that in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stop_route 
( id       INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, stop_id  INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref stop'
, route_id INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref route'
, UNIQUE_KEY stop_route_UX1 (stop_id, route_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_stop_route_stop (stop_id) REFERENCES stop(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_stop_route_route (route_id) REFERENCES route(id)
}
```

If `route` is not an entity in your model, then remove the foreign key constraint.

---

**Entity-Relationship model**

I don't know your entity-relationship model.

But I suspect that there's actually a *many-to-many* relationship between `route` and `stop`. To resolve that, we'd introduce a new "relationship" table with foreign keys pointing to both "stop" and "route".

And I'm thinking that `arrival_time` is not independent of route. The question I'm asking is if every `route` has the same 50 `arrival_time` at a given `stop`? Or, does each `route` have it's own set of `arrival_time` for a given `stop`. (I'm thinking it's the latter.)

- a `route` arrives at zero, one or more `stop`
- a `stop` is serviced by zero, one or more `route`

We resolve the many-to-many by introducing a relationship table

```
route >--- route_stop ---< stop
```

---

(Personally, in terms of naming things, I think the `route_stop` relationship table above should be named a "stop", and the `stop` entity table should be a "location".

On a schedule, a vehicle makes on a particular `route` makes a "stop" at a particular "location", at (or close to) a particular `arrival_time`.) But that's just nomenclature. Just depends on how you name things.

```
CREATE TABLE route_stop 
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, route_id INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref route' 
, stop_id INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref stop'
, UNIQUE KEY route_stop_UX1 (route_id, stop_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_route_stop_route FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES route(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_route_stop_stop FOREIGN KEY (stop_id) REFERENCES stop(id)
)

CREATE TABLE arrival_time 
( id            INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, stop_route_id INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref route_stop'
, weekday     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, arrivaltime TIME NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT FK_arrival_time_stop_route 
    FOREIGN KEY (route_stop_id) REFERENCES stop_route(id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Each route has its own set. I am tring to create them but for example for stop_route table I am getting `version for the right syntax to use near 'stop_route_UX1 (stop_id, route_id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_stop_route_stop (stop_id) RE' at line 5 `

Comment: It is UNIQUE KEY and not UNIQUE_KEY i coorected it but I am getting now `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(stop_id) REFERENCES stop(id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_stop_route_route (route_id) REFER' at line 6 `

Comment: `Personally, in terms of naming things, I think the route_stop relationship table above` do you mean stop_route above or route_stop  below?

Comment: The `stop_route` table in the first part of my answer was meant to represent the data that way that you have it, but breaking the list of routes out into an array (as I showed).Then the rows added to the `stop_route` with a given `stop_id` represents the array of `route_id`. I named the table that way because that represents "route" as a repeating attribute of `stop`. The second part of my answer, I turned that around. It would have been clearer if I had renamed `stop` as `loc` and `route_stop` as just `stop`. A 1:M rel.between `route` and `stop`, and 1:M rel. between `loc` and `stop`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to create a relational database structure. And you want to have a relation between stops and routes table.

So assuming that one stop can belong to several routes and one route can have several stops that's many to many relationship between tables.

For instance you can take a look here 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_many_to_many_mapping.htm

how to implement this relation in Hibernate.