# How to count comma separated arrays retrieved from database table that include specific value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a MySQL table like this;

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ id ║ comma_separated_stuff ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5         ║
║  2 ║ 1, 2, 5               ║
║  3 ║ 3, 7                  ║
║  4 ║ 4, 8                  ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

I managed to get each rows into arrays as array[0], array[1], array[2] and array[3]. The question is how to count "how many of the comma-separated-arrays include -for example- '5'?"

Comment: so what have you tried so far? can you provide your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column

Comment: This is precisely why we always recommend normalising your database rather than storing comma-separated values

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah, it's a typical antipattern. God knows, how will he join the tables.

Comment: @MarkBaker I am now normalising my database, sir. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//how many of the comma-separated-arrays include for example '5'
$array = array(
'1, 2, 3, 4, 5',
'1, 2, 5',
'3, 7',
'4, 8',
);

$n = 5;
$sum = 0;
//Split the strings to arrays of numbers
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $data = explode(', ', $value);
    if (in_array($n, $data))
    {
        ++$sum;
    }
}

//prints 2
print $sum;
```

Comment: Since this one uses ', ' in explode(); it doesn't count the first items in the arrays as there is not comma+space before them. So I will take this answer and your humiliating comment above as advice to work with one more table and join them instead of keeping comma separated values in a single table. Thanks.

Comment: @Terby "Since this one uses ', ' in explode(); it doesn't count the first items in the arrays as there is not comma+space before them" - no, actually it does. The error was caused by `array_search`, not by explode. I changed it to `in_array`, and now it works correctly if 5 is the 1-st number in the list.

Comment: @Terby Sorry, I didn't want to humiliate you. Just wanted to say, that it's an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

the following two examples if you would like to count how many keys among the array itself by :

```
<?php

$a[0] = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5';
$a[1] = '1, 2, 5';
$a[2] = '3, 7 ';
$a[3] = '4, 8';

$resulta = count($a);
print $resulta;// Output 4
?>
```

Another one:

```
 <?php
 $b = array ('1, 2, 3, 4, 5','1, 2, 5' ,'3, 7','4, 8');

 $resultb = count($b);

 print $resultb;// Output 4
 ?>
```

the following one if you would like to count the number of comma from string :

```
    $text = 'This , is, , a , test a,a,';
    echo substr_count($text, ','); // Output 6 , will give the number of comma in each one
```

Comment: These are not for counting the ones that include the specific value but thanks anyway Mr. Elhag. Thanks for the effort and time.

Comment: ok , i will be glad to know what you mean by specific values? give me an example