# Rails 4, Saving arrays in Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I'm having problems saving my data of arrays into the database.
Currently, I am using a nested form and have 3 models as shown below.
**deal.rb**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_days, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_days, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**deal_day.rb**

```
class DealDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
  has_many :deal_times, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_times, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**deal_time.rb**

```
class DealTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal_day
end
```

My objective is to allow users to select multiple days where the deal is ongoing in a checkbox. For example if a user selects Monday and Tuesday, I want the array to have monday and tuesday in it. 
Shown below is my current database for **deal_day:**

```
create_table "deal_days", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "deal_id"
    t.string   "day",        default: [], array: true
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The form for deal_day is as follows in a file called **_deal_day_fields:**

```
<fieldset>
  Enter Days (e.g Mon - Fri)<br>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Mon" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Tue" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Wed" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Thur" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Fri" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Sat" /></td>
  <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "day[]" value = "Sun" /></td>
  <%= link_to "Delete", '#', class: "remove_fields" %><br>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= f.fields_for :deal_times do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'deal_time_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add another time period", f, :deal_times %>
</fieldset>
```

For the **deal controller params**, I have set it to be so:

```
    params.require(:deal).permit(:name_of_deal, :type_of_deal, :description, :start_date, :expiry_date, :location, :t_c,
                             :pushed,:redeemable, :multiple_use, :image,
                             deal_days_attributes: [:id, {day: []}, :_destroy,
                                                    deal_times_attributes: [:id, :started_at, :ended_at, :_destroy]])
```

When, I run the form, all my data is saved properly into the database except for the array of **:day**. It is saved into the database as [].
I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column

Comment: If i'm right test by selecting sunday, this will save in db, because if you have N   name = "day[]"   name = "day[]" .......  last one will be overridden and sent to db to store.

Comment: hi @praaveen, I tried what you suggested but it still saves only [].
I've read up on the link you posted and if I cannot reach a solution I might just create 7 different attributes to name monday to sunday. Thank you though!

Comment: check in you controller by printing params.

Comment: Why do you want to store an array? SQL arrays are a huge pain to query. I'd recommend you store a boolean for each day of the week – you get to keep your checkbox structure, and you have much easier data types to deal with and to query.

Comment: Hi after printing it out it shows 
"deal_days_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "deal_times_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"started_at(1i)"=>"1", etc...)
Then "day"=>["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun"].
Strangely, day attribute is not within deal_days_attribute, also it is not saved into database although everything is written

Comment: The core issue I see here is that the checkbox inputs are not going to be in the right place in the HTML POST message, and thus they will be in the wrong place in the controller's params object.  
It seems to me that the checkboxes should be built within the `<% f.fields for :deal_times %>` block, HOWEVER I am confused by the data model here, in that these values somehow should tie in with a User record (a ActiveRecord that has foreign keys to user and maybe deal?).

Comment: Hi @rodamn, I missed out a certain part. 
I am fairly certain it is in the correct field as it is rendered from another field which is the deal_form, here is the code:
 ` <%= f.fields_for :deal_days do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'deal_day_fields', f: builder %>
 <% end %>`

Comment: Yeah, so by hardcoding inputs yourself, you are missing out on some of the "magic" that Rails includes when you use its form helpers (like f.text_field, etc). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `days[]` within `deal_days` in your controllers params as you posted in your strong parameters require/permit statement, you can build this with form helpers (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

Here is what it would look like:

```
# app/views/deals/_form.html.erb
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :deal_days do |f_days| %>
        <%= fields_for 'deal[deal_days][]', f_days.object do |f_days_array| %>
            <%= f_days_array.check_box 'Monday' %>
            <%= f_days_array.check_box 'Tuesday' %>
            ...etc..
        <%= f.fields_for :deal_times do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'deal_time_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Pretty sure that's it, or pretty close. I based this off of the code in section 7.3 of the Rails guide above. You should definitely read up on that whole page if you are still confused.

Caveat: This solution won't reach your stated objective, because this data is currently associated with the deal, while it needs to be associated with a user in addition to a specific deal/deal day. But that's another problem.

Comment: To further clarify the difference, by setting your inputs to `name="day[]"`, the web browser literally puts them in the root as `day[0] = true, day[1] = true`. If you had `name=deal[deal_day][]`, you would get `deal => {deal_day => {0: true, 1: true, ...}}` and what you actually need is `deal_day_attributes => {0: true, 1: false}' using the `fields_for`  builds this automatically.