# SQL query with JOIN involving two criteria from same table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working in MS Access trying to iron out an SQL statement that works.  On a form I have a combobox that displays a list of employees.  I have a separate dialog form that allows the user to select multiple items in a listbox.  Each item represents a certification.  Each employee can have any number and combination of certifications.  Ultimately I just want to update the RowSource property of the combobox to reflect the new filtered data by assigning a proper SQL statement.

If I want to filter the list on the combobox of employees, I use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name 
FROM 
    Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    Emp_Certs ON Employees.Employee_ID = Emp_Certs.Employee_ID 
WHERE 
    (((Employees.Active_Member) = Yes) 
      AND ((Emp_Certs.Employee_ID) = [Employees].[Employee_ID]) 
     AND ((Emp_Certs.Cert_ID) = 1)) 
ORDER BY 
    Employees.Last_Name;
```

If I run this query it works because I'm assigning only one value to `Emp_Certs.Cert_ID`. But when I add another like this:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name 
FROM 
    Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    Emp_Certs ON Employees.Employee_ID = Emp_Certs.Employee_ID 
WHERE 
    (((Employees.Active_Member) = Yes) 
      AND ((Emp_Certs.Employee_ID) = [Employees].[Employee_ID]) 
      AND ((Emp_Certs.Cert_ID) = 1) 
      AND ((Emp_Certs.Cert_ID) = 4)) 
ORDER BY Employees.Last_Name;
```

I get an empty set. That's not what I expected.  The table Emp_Certs clearly has several employees that have the combination of certifications 1 and 4.
Could someone please explain how this is supposed to be written if I want to indicate more that one Cert_ID and have the employee record show up only once in the combobox.  I don't need the employee records showing up multiple times in the combobox.

This might help:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join tables, you basically query off a result set containing all the combinations of rows from those joined tables that your where clauses then operate off of.  Since you are joining to the `Emp_Certs` table just once and linking only by Employee_ID, you are getting a result set that looks like this (only showing two columns):

```
Last_Name    Cert_ID
Jones        1
Jones        3
Jones        4
Smith        1
Smith        2
```

Your where clause then filters those rows, only accepting rows that have `Cert_ID = 1` AND `Cert_ID = 4`, which is impossible so you should not get any rows.

I'm not sure if Access has limititations, but in SQL Server you could handle it in at least two ways:

1) Link to the table twice, joining for each of the certifications.  Table alias 'a' joins to the Emp_Certs table where the Cert_ID is 1 and table alias 'b' joins to the Emp_Certs table where the Cert_ID is 4:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name 
FROM 
    Employees 
INNER JOIN 
    Emp_Certs a ON Employees.Employee_ID = a.Employee_ID AND a.Cert_ID = 1
INNER JOIN 
    Emp_Certs b ON Employees.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID AND b.Cert_ID = 4
WHERE 
    Employees.Active_Member = Yes
ORDER BY Employees.Last_Name;
```

This gives you a result set that looks like this (Smith doesn't show up because the join criteria doesn't allow any rows unless the employee can link to table `a` and `b`):

```
Last_Name    a.Cert_ID   b.Cert_ID
Jones        1           4
```

2) Use sub-selects in the where clause to filter the employee id on ids with those certifications (looks like [Access 2010 supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff192664(v=office.14).aspx)):

```
SELECT 
    Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name 
FROM 
    Employees 
WHERE 
    Active_Member = Yes
    AND Employee_ID in (SELECT Employee_ID FROM Emp_Certs WHERE Cert_ID = 1)
    AND Employee_ID in (SELECT Employee_ID FROM Emp_Certs WHERE Cert_ID = 4)
ORDER BY Employees.Last_Name;
```

Comment: This helped the best.  I tried the first scenario but kept getting syntax errors.  The second one with sub-selects worked without a hitch.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR` operator in `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
    (((Employees.Active_Member) = Yes) 
      AND ((Emp_Certs.Employee_ID) = [Employees].[Employee_ID]) 
      AND ( Emp_Certs.Cert_ID  = 1 OR
            Emp_Certs.Cert_ID  = 4 ) 
ORDER BY Employees.Last_Name;
```

because of `Emp_Certs.Cert_ID  = 1 and Emp_Certs.Cert_ID  = 4` is always `FALSE`

Also the `((Emp_Certs.Employee_ID) = [Employees].[Employee_ID])` condition is redundant due to `INNER JOIN` condition

Comment: I got rid of the redundant clause, but same affect.

Comment: I tried that. The result returns two employees that have just certification 1 and two that have both 1 and 4. Also, the employees that have both appear in the combobox twice. That's not good.  The resultset should return only employees that have both certifications. Not just one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't working because Emp_Certs is probably only storing a single value. You can't check that the value is both 1 and 4. If your goal is to store multiple items into a single field, take a look here:

[How to store array or multiple values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column)

You may be better off storing different certifications on different fields.

Comment: FYI..Emp_Certs is a link table to handle one to many relationship.  It contains only two fields: Employee_ID and Cert_ID.  The Employees.Employee_ID field points to the Emp_Certs.Employee_ID field and the Certifications.Cert_ID points to the Emp_Certs.Cert_ID field. Thus I can place in the Emp_Certs table multiple entries regarding the same employee.

Answer (score 0):

What you are selecting now is for a row that contains both employee certs 1 and 4.  You would want a query which would be implemented in access something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employees.Employee_ID, Employees.Last_Name, Employee.First_Name
FROM Emp_Certs AS a 
INNER JOIN (Emp_Certs INNER JOIN Employees ON Emp_Certs.Employee_Id = Employees.Employee_ID) ON a.Employee_ID = Employees.Employee_ID
WHERE (((Emp_Certs.CertId)=1) AND ((a.CertId)=4) AND ((Employees.Active_Member)=Yes))
ORDER BY Employee.Last;
```

This Edit has been tested as working in Access.  It returns the results you requested.  The key thing to remember when using query builder is that you have to join the Emp_Certs table twice.

Comment: This looks promising but when I run this I get: Syntax error (Missing operator) :   (((Employees.Active_Member) = Yes) AND ((a.Cert_ID) = 1))
INNER JOIN 
    Emp_Certs AS b
ON Employees.Employee_ID = b.Employee_ID 
WHERE 
    (((Employees.Active_Member) = Yes) AND ((b.Cert_ID) = 4))  It looks ok to me.  I don't see where the error is though.

Comment: As noted from one of the other responders, the following condition: ((a.Employee_ID) = [Employees].[Employee_ID]) can be omitted as it is redundant and covered with the INNER JOIN statement.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it should work, but it doesn't.  I still keep getting Syntax error (Missing operator)

Comment: Try it using this syntax.  This has been tested in Access