# How to store an array in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that you can "reference" another table using a foreign key in SQL, which will make a connection between that entry in Table 1(the FK) and the primary key in Table 2.

I want to extend the concept so that there are n 'Table 2's.

The task I have at hand is that Table 1 denotes a list of tasks, and Table 2 is the task itself, and I want to store n such tasks for each tasklist.

I'm using postgres specifically, but I'd like to know the answer in vanilla SQL (so that it's easier to understand).

Comment: This question does not show any effort for me. What have you tried? If the answer would be `nothing`, have a look at the [tour] and recherche at w3schools.

Comment: This is a new concept for me, I'm looking for some pointers. And yes, I have read some books, but my boss is bearing down on me.

Comment: have a look at [http://www.w3schools.com/sql] that are real the basics. Maybe skip through directly to the Constraints

Comment: @inetphantom Checked that out, not much help. Thanks anyway. All that's there is stuff I already know(pk,fk,unique,check,default).

Comment: A related question I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to extend the concept so that there are n 'Table 2's.
>
> The task I have at hand is that Table 1 denotes a list of tasks, and
>   Table 2 is the task itself, and I want to store n such tasks for each
>   tasklist.

Think it the other way around.

Each `task`(table2) must have the FK to the corresponding PK in table 1. And there may be many tasks referencing the same PK in table 1 (what is basically your "list of tasks" then).

This is a `1:N` relationship. And the FK should be designed on the "N-side" and not on the "1-Side" of the relationship.

Comment: What's cwallenpoole saying in the selected answer in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360739/how-to-store-array-or-multiple-values-in-one-column?rq=1 Do I need a similar map-table in my implementation?

Comment: No, you need a mapping table for `N:M`-Relationships. For `1:N` relationships it is sufficient and advisable to put the FK inside the table of the `N-side` which is referencing the (one) corresponding datarow in the other table on the `1-side`.

Comment: As long as a single task always belong to *one* specific tasklist you have a `1:N` relationship here.

Comment: It is VERY essential to learn at least the basics about [ER diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). Then it is very much straight-forward how to do a good and [normalized database design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I agree. Now that I have created the tables, I realized that I actually needed three tables: Table 1 was a table of tasklists, second was a map of list_to_task, and third was the tasks table. It was kind of `1:N:N^2`, i.e a list of lists. The difference between the two was getting to me all week.

Comment: If it were a simple `1:N`, all it would take is a PK on Table 1 and a FK on Table 2 mapping to Table1's `id`. But it was a level higher. Thanks for all your help, and sorry for wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

A relational database is based on relations.  So, let's create the tables first.

```
TaskList
--------
TaskList ID
Task ID
Task Number
Task Priority
Start Time Stamp
End Time Stamp
...
```

TaskList ID is the primary key.  Task ID is a foreign key to the Task table.  Task Number is a number that the user assigns to the task.  Task Priority is a priority that the user assigns to the task.

We have 2 tables so we can separate tasks from their chronological order in the TaskList table.  We also save a tiny bit of space when you have repeated tasks.

```
Task
----
Task ID
Task Description
...
```

In Java, we don't have relations.  We have objects.  So, it's fine to create a Java Object for a task.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Task {

    private int taskNumber;
    private int taskPriority;

    private Calendar startTimestamp;
    private Calendar finishTimestamp;

    private String description;

    public int getTaskNumber() {
        return taskNumber;
    }

    public void setTaskNumber(int taskNumber) {
        this.taskNumber = taskNumber;
    }

    public int getTaskPriority() {
        return taskPriority;
    }

    public void setTaskPriority(int taskPriority) {
        this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
    }

    public Calendar getStartTimestamp() {
        return startTimestamp;
    }

    public void setStartTimestamp(Calendar startTimestamp) {
        this.startTimestamp = startTimestamp;
    }

    public Calendar getFinishTimestamp() {
        return finishTimestamp;
    }

    public void setFinishTimestamp(Calendar finishTimestamp) {
        this.finishTimestamp = finishTimestamp;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

As you can see, you'll have to read the TaskList table and the Task table to create the Task object.  You'll have to write a row to both the TaskList table and the Task Table when your user creates a new Task object.

You create a List of Task instances when you join the TaskList and Task tables, and select more than one row.

Comment: `TaskList ID is the primary key. Task ID is a foreign key to the Task table. ...` which implies that there can only be one task per list. Either you need a composite primary key on (tasklist_id,task_number), or : see the other answer.

Comment: @joop I ended up creating a third table which mapped from tasklists to tasks. It only contained its own PK and a FK to the main `task_lists` table.

Comment: @Gilbert is this JPA or just Java? If JPA, won't I need annotations?

Comment: @cst1992: I was thinking of a plain old java object.